# An English translation of the paper "Expansion in Fourier series and integrals with Bessel functions" by Levitan

Tags: reference-request

In my research, I've come across some results which can be found in the aforementioned paper by Levitan (see [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=6834&option_lang=eng)). Several authors simply paraphrase the work in the paper, particularly the results about the Bessel translation operator; however I am not interested just in the result but also in the proofs contained therein. Unfortunately, I cannot read Russian to tell what exactly it says. I can put pieces here or there together, but, for the most part, it's inaccessible. I was wondering if there was an English translation anywhere. For such a highly cited paper (110+ times!), I would think that an English translation would be floating around somewhere but I can't seem to find one. Or alternatively if there is an English reference which proves a lot of the results contained therein (not necessarily a translation), that would work as well. If worse comes to worst, I might try to recreate the proofs myself by piecing together the equations. If it comes to that, I'll throw it up on arXiv for ease of accessibility.

Comment: I'm a native Russian speaker so I can translate a needed part of paper (the whole paper is quite long). The only problem is that my English is quite poor)

Comment: @user144765 Your English is fine! Would you mind translating Section 7 of the paper? It's what I'm most interested in for my purposes. If you do, I'll award you a nice bounty as it's quite a lot to ask :)

Comment: Here is the table of contents:
1. Expansion in Fourier-Bessel Series
2. Expansion in Fourier-Hankel Integral
3. Riemann Method
4. Euler-Poisson Equation
5. Poisson Formula
6. Taylor-Delsarte Formula
7. Properties of $T^y$ Operators 
8. Sonin's and Poisson's Operators
9. Relation between Sonin's and Poisson's Operators
10. Fourier-Stieltjes-Bessel integrals
11. Generalized Positive-Definite Functions
12. Integral Representation of Generalized Positive-Definite Functions

Comment: OK, I'll translate the section 7. Just give me one or two days. I'll omit the formulas in text (I don't know TeX) and replace them with only its numerals (e.g (7.11))?

Comment: That works great for me. I can fill in the $\LaTeX$ as I go. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I had to use LaTeX because of not all formulas in the text had numbers. So as it was my attempt to use it here is the [PDF file with translation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8ZLCPd_0uSSVgzY0NKeFR2NWM/view?usp=sharing) but text in it can't be copied). The original [LaTeX file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-8ZLCPd_0uSS0NGV0hfcUg0Vkk/view?usp=sharing) is also there. 
I tried to translate as closer to the original as possible almost word-to-word. The formulas which initially had numbers in text are omitted. If you need any clarification just let me know. Hope it will help.

Comment: This is great work! Why don't you make your comment an answer and I'll accept it/give you a nice bounty for it. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Thanks, but bounty is not required. I'm glad it can be helpful.
BTW, you should change any "with respect to" in translation with "because of" or "due to" - I misunderstood the meaning of that idiom. In the original text it always means consequence, literally "in the strength of...", which relates to English "because of" or "due to".